# Application stops receiving GCM notifications after inactivity (does android force applications into stopped state?)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

I have an application that correctly receives notifications, even when the application has been killed by swiping. However, after a longer period of inactivity (e.g. application not used for ~2 weeks) the notifications stop getting delivered. The behavior is consistent with applications that have been force stopped (http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols). However, I am confident that the application has not been force stopped.

To elaborate, the device receives the GCM message and the intent is triggered, but the application is not available to process it. See log excerpt below for details on what happens when notification is sent.

```
03-30 19:43:24.596: I/GCM(4931): GCM message com.company.application 0:1459359805552536%60ff11d7f9fd7ecd
03-30 19:43:24.606: W/GCM-DMM(4931): broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.company.application (has extras) }
```

Does android sometimes force idle applications into a stopped state? Is there reason for this to occur other than a stopped state?

If it matters, notifications are implemented using Urban Airship, but I had similiar problems before migrating from Parse.

Code excerpts below.

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.application"
    android:versionCode="27"
    android:versionName="1.31">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.company.application.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.company.application.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        ...

        <activity android:name=".ParseDeepLinkActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <!-- Handles any vnd.company.application://deeplink URI's -->
                <data android:scheme="vnd.company.application" android:host="deeplink" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Application**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        UAirship.takeOff(this, new UAirship.OnReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAirshipReady(UAirship airship) {
                // Enable user notifications
                airship.getPushManager().setUserNotificationsEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the priority of a message? If not, you should set it as a High priority. GCM attempts to deliver high priority messages immediately, allowing the GCM service to wake a sleeping device when possible and open a network connection to your app server. Apps with instant messaging, chat, or voice call alerts, for example, generally need to open a network connection and make sure GCM delivers the message to the device without delay.
Note: Setting your messages to high priority contributes more to a battery drain compared to normal priority messages.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I don't think this is the error though because I don't get the notifications even when the device is awake. I also don't know if Urban Airship lets me set the GCM priority.

Comment: What version of Urban Airship are you using? Parse used the deprecated gcm registration way, while Urban Airship using Google Play Services and the new instance ids (if on a newer version). Is this widespread or a certain device/manufacturer?

Comment: I use the latest version of Urban Airship ('com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:7.0.+' in by Gradle file)

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing a WakeLock object? Do you set a keepalive value for your GCM messages? I suggest you start by checking both points or post some more code / details so we can understand the whole scope :)

Comment: These are questions you typically ask in a comment

Comment: Thanks for replying! I do not have a WakeLock object. The documentation for Urban Airship does not specify that I have to use one. Where do you suggest that I use one? I also do not know of keepalive values for GCM messages as I believe that Urban Aiship handles that for me, but please correct me if I'm wrong. I added my Application class and most of the Android manifest to my original question if that helps.

Comment: Urban Airship uses the com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver which uses wakelocks. I dont believe this is the issue.

Comment: How are you registering the app with GCM? Most of my apps use GCM and always get the notifications delivered, the key is to keep the app (and accordingly the device) registered with the GCM server. If you do that on startup try to create a timer which will refresh the app's registration every 13 days for example.

Comment: Thank you again for the tip Aksaçlı, but I use Urban Airship (https://www.urbanairship.com/) so I don't have manual control over GCM.